# react-router navigate to external url

Tags: redirect, reactjs, react-router

I'm on react-router@3.0.0-alpha.2 using the onEnter hook on a route and attempting to redirect the user to an external url (outside of my app).  I'd like to do this on the server side.  I noticed that the match function callback has a redirect location but that appears to be a route within the app.  Is there any way to redirect users to another website entirely?

Answer (score 1):

Since the user is leaving your app, it's not related to `react-router`.

If you're using express, just call `res.redirect()` ([which defaults to 302](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect)) from within the route/middleware that you want to trigger the redirect.

Something like:

```
app.get('/go-elsewhere', (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('http://elsewhere.com');
});
```

(untested, I hope that's right)